# Setting up Snowflake ODBC with Azure AD SSO for Excel/Power BI

Tags: excel, azure, odbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm looking to use an ODBC connection in Excel to pull data from our DW, we access Snowflake via Azure AD so we don't have a password.

I got the User DSN setup fine, using only the following parameters:

- server (format [organisation].[region].snowflakecomputing.com
- tracing (defaulted to 4)
- authenticator = externalbrowser

I can't test the connection because there's no username or password, and from the documentation on Snowflake (https://snowflakecommunity.force.com/s/article/HOW-TO-connect-to-Snowflake-authenticating-with-Azure-AD-SSO-from-MS-Excel-ODBC-driver) it suggests that when trying to connect via the ODBC in Excel, I should get a browser window to sign-in to Azure, but this isn't happening?

Any ideas what might be amiss?

Comment: You can put at least the username from Azure and that should be enough.

Comment: Thanks @Sergiu, I've done that and I'm getting a new browser tab with the message "Your identity was confirmed and propagated to Snowflake ODBC driver. You can close this window now and go back where you started from." but a credential authentication message on the ODBC connection in Excel. I guess I still need to find the right password. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

When you mention that you access SF from Azure AD, does that imply that the SF app is listed on the Azure AD Tile for users and they select it to be given access? If so, then that is called as the IDP initiated SSO but that cannot be directly used logging in from Excel to SF. I am not sure if there is any plugin for excel that can do this but if using "externalbrowser" then the  authn expects the user / pwd conmbination.

If looking to do without the password part, then I think the Seamless SSO would be needed. Check this out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-sso

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Srinath. When I say we access it from Azure AD, what I mean is we don't use a login to get into SF, we have a "Sign-in using Azure AD" button on the login screen to the SF application/page.

Comment: Yes, in that case it would be redirecting to the AAD login screen where the user and password would need to be passed,right?

Comment: yes, it should be, but instead what I get is the standard ODBC driver setup screen (offering Default or Custom, Windows, and Database login). From here, I have tried all three and I get the same result, a browser window/tab opens and the message: "Your identity was confirmed and propagated to Snowflake ODBC driver. You can close this window now and go back where you started from." is returned, however back in Excel I just have an "We couldn't authenticate with the credentials provided" message returned.